# jQuery is not working. When I click the submit button on my form nothing is happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a webpage for a number game but I cannot get my jQuery to work. I am pretty sure all my placements are in the right spots but nothing happens when I click on the Submit button. Please help!

EDIT: I have also added my JavaScript code to make it easier to understand what I am trying to do.

My HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Ping-Pong</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>The Ping Pong Game!</h1>
      <div>
        <form id="digit">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input">Type in a number:</label>
            <input id="number" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <div id="output"><p>Thanks for playing!</p>
          <ul id="list">

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

MY JQUERY CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#digit").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var userInput = $("#number").val();
      $("#submit").click(function () {
        $("#output").append(input(userInput));
        toggle();
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? What's `input` in `append(input(userInput))`?

Comment: Why have you place a `jQuery` click function within the submit function? remove the click function and I'm sure you will find the `append()` will run assuming `input()` is something you have working somewhere else. Not sure what you expect `toggle()` to do since it isn't attached to anything.

Comment: I am not getting any errors in the console. append(input(userInput)) is meant to show the result as a list in the html <ul> tags.

Comment: "nothing is happening" is wrong. What is happening is exactly **what you specified**. When your form is submitted, you attach an event handler to your button. Inside that event handler you're appending `undefined` to `#output`. Then you're calling an undefined function called `toggle`. On first submit the click handler is **not executed**.

Comment: You *should* be getting errors in the console; I am. And why are you preventing the default submit event?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to had a listener on the submit button. Your submit listener is doing the job.

input() function is not needed to. Here is what I think you are trying to get :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#digitreplacer").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var userInput = $("#number").val();
      $("#output #list").append("<li>"+userInput+"</li>");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Beep-Boop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>The Number Game!</h1>
      <div>
        <form id="digitreplacer">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input">Type in a number:</label>
            <input id="number" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
 
        <div id="output"><p>Thanks for playing!</p>
          <ul id="list">

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also what is toggle() doing ?

Here is a Codepen demo : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/GyzOKo

Comment: ok... I made some changes and now when I click the submit button something happens but there are no results popping up. would it help if I also post the Back-end logic?

Comment: here is the modified JQUERY:

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#digitreplacer").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      userInput = $("#number").val();
      // $("#submit").click(function () {
        $("#output").append(userInput);
        toggle();
      // });
    });
  });

And toggle() i calling this function: 

function toggle() {
  $("#digitreplacer").toggle();
  $("#output").toggle();
}

Comment: Please take a look at this : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/GyzOKo If think it's what you are trying to do :)

Comment: This game is supposed to be similar to fizz buzz

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to get.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var userInput;
    $("#submit").click(function () {
      userInput = $("#number").val();
      $("#list").append("<li>" + userInput + "</li>");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Beep-Boop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>The Number Game!</h1>
      <div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input">Type in a number:</label>
            <input id="number" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>

          <button class="btn" id="submit">Submit</button>

        <div id="output"><p>Thanks for playing!</p>
          <ul id="list">

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No sorry. This game is supposed to be similar to fizz buzz. I have also added my JS code up top in case that will help